# How to pause the "for" loop until getting response

Tags: c#, for-loop, voip

I am using a `for` loop for making Calls for a list of numbers.
I want to take the first number from the list and make a call and to wait for the response and then proceed to the next number in the list.
I have used `AutoResetEvent` to do this.But it is not working.

```
for (int k = 0; k < list_Items.Count; k++) {
    Number_To_Call = "9" + list_Items[k].ToString();

    phoneCall.Start();

    waitingToPickUp.Set(); //AutoReset Event

    Thread.Sleep();

    waitingToPickUp.WaitOne();

    string detector = VoiceDetected;

    if (detector == "Machine") {
        //code
    } else if (detector == "Human") {
        //code
    } else {
        //code
    }
}
```

Code for getting response form the call

```
void phoneCall_CallStateChanged(object sender, VoIPEventArgs<CallState> e)
        {
            if (e.Item.IsInCall())
            {
                phoneCallAudioReceiver.AttachToCall(phoneCall);
                phoneCallAudioSender.AttachToCall(phoneCall);
                manchineDetector.Start();
                waitingToPickUp.Set();

                string str = VoiceDetected;

            }
            else if (e.Item.IsCallEnded())
            {
                phoneCallAudioReceiver.Detach();
                phoneCallAudioSender.Detach();
                manchineDetector.Stop();
                phoneCall = null;

                //Number_To_Call = string.Empty;

                InvokeOnGUIThread(() =>
                {
                    Number_To_Call = string.Empty;
                });
            }
        }
```

Code for Detecting Machine or Human

```
void manchineDetector_DetectionCompleted(object sender, VoIPEventArgs<AnswerMachineDetectionResult> e)
        {
            try
            {    
                string VoiceDetected = e.Item.ToString();    

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: You may need to mention which VOIP software you're using to assist people with your query.

Comment: `Set` and immediately `WaitOne` makes no sense... Are your sure you have not make copy-paste error (I'd expect `Reset` before making call, not `Set` after....)

Comment: You need another thread to set the event.  Is there a way to tell if the call is still pending after the call to `Start`?

Comment: yes..I got an event.I will add that code here

Answer (score 0):

`Set` and immediately `WaitOne` makes no sense - wait will not need to wait for anything and immediately continue.

Most likely should be reset-call-wait:

```
  waitingToPickUp.Reset(); 
  phoneCall.Start();
  waitingToPickUp.WaitOne();
```